# Gauss law in gravitation

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-gravity, gauss-law

Is it possible to use Gauss's law of electromagnetism, (The net electric flux through any closed surface is equal to $1⁄\epsilon$ times the net electric charge enclosed within that surface.) to calculate the gravitational field at point by making certain changes, i.e, by replacing electric flux with gravitational flux, $1⁄\epsilon$ with $1/(4\pi\,G)$, and charge with mass?

Comment: See e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_law_for_gravity).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use Gauss's law for gravity.

$$\nabla\cdot\vec{g} = 4 \pi\, G\, \rho $$

or

$$ \oint \vec{g}\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec{a} = 4 \pi\, G\, M_\mathrm{enc} $$

where $\vec{g}$ is the gravitational field (equivalently, acceleration due to gravity), $\rho$ is mass density, and $M_\mathrm{enc}$ is the total mass enclosed by the Gaussian surface.

When you make the comparison to Gauss's law for electric fields, you can see how the constants work out the way that they do:

$$E = \frac{1}{4\pi\, \epsilon_0} \frac{Q}{r^2}, \quad\quad g = G\, \frac{M}{r^2}, $$

so $1/\epsilon_0\rightarrow 4\pi\, G$.

One common use for Gauss's law for gravity is to determine the gravitational field strength at a given depth inside the Earth.  It is very similar to the calculation for the electric field inside a charged, insulating sphere.

Comment: In my original post I messed up the constants... fixed

Comment: Indeed the close match between flux of the field in Einstein's treatment to Newton's for a spherically symmetric weak field can be demonstrated using this Gauss' Law approach.

Comment: There is a small mistake : the electrostatic force is repulsive between charges of equal signs while gravitation is attractive : $$\vec E={1\over 4\pi\varepsilon_0}{Q\over r^2}\vec u_r,\quad \vec g=-{\cal G}{M\over r^2}\vec u_r$$ There is therefore a minus sign $1/\varepsilon_0\rightarrow -4\pi{\cal G}$ and Gauss law reads $${\rm div}\ \!\vec g=-4\pi{\cal G}\rho_m$$

Answer (score 1):

Gauss Law for Gravity basically says that the total gravitational flux emanating from a sphere enclosing the Earth is $4 \pi G M$.

Now divide this by the total surface of the sphere $4 \pi R^2$ with $R$ the radius of the Earth.

The result is $\frac{GM}{R^2}$ giving the gravitational flux density. If you calculate the numerical result you get $9.81\mathrm{m/s^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, should be! Unfortunately, Einstein GR does not satisfy it...
Static, (i.e. from immobility) acceleration calculated from geodesic curves formulae, does not satisfy Gauss law nor for reference space (map) - what is obvious, nor for a local observer (on the surface of a planet. For the planet, of radius equal 1.5 r_s (Schwarzschild), relativistic acceleration is (about) twice this predicted by Gauss theorem.

Comment: Huh?  Birchoff's theorem gives you something not entirely unlike Gauss's law in full GR for the spherically symmetric case.

Comment: Thanks to Hamilton's principle, it can be proved that Gauss's theorem for gravity must be true also for curved spacetime. Even if Einstein's solution does not satisfy this condition, it happily satisfies Gauss's theorem quite exactly already above 10 Schwarzschild radii.
Where is any contrast between Gauss and Birchoff's?

Comment: you're the one that says that Gauss's theorem for gravity isn't satisfied in this answer.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer What I say is not very important, but if you calculate the local acceleration in the gravitational field yourself and integrate it on the surface of the surrounding sphere, you will see that the resulting value is larger by  sqrt{frac{r}{r-r_s}}  than the Gaussian requirement.  (Only internal acceleration can be considered from the point of view of conservation of energy!).